# Finding a parametric representation for a boundary of $S$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametrization

the question is:
Let $\Omega$ denote the conical region $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \leq z \leq 2$.
Find a parametric representation $x(u,v)$ for $S = \partial \Omega$, the boundary of $\Omega$. (You'll need to split it into two parts).
I have no clue how to do this. What does it mean by boundary? Does it mean $z=2$ and $z = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$?How would I approach finding a parametric for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I plotted the region for you. The region $\Omega$ is this solid cone. The boundary $\partial \Omega$ has two parts:

- the curved outer surface, given by the equation $z = \sqrt {x^2 + y^2}$
- the flat upper surface, given by $z = 2$.

[image]

To parametrise each of these boundary surfaces, you could first parametrise the $x$ and $y$ coordinates using plane polar coordinates. (If you decide to take this approach, you should think carefully about the range of the radial coordinate.) And once you have specified your parametrisation of $x$ and $y$, the $z$ coordinate is then determined by the equation of the surface, which is different depending on whether you're doing the curved surface or the flat surface. I don't want to say more at this stage, but feel free to leave a comment if you would like more clarification.

Comment: Thanks. Would the parametrizaion be $x = u \cos v, y = u \sin v, z = u$ for $u \in [0,2], v \in [0,2 \pi]$?

Comment: Also, what do you mean that it's different depending if I'm "doing" the curved surface or the flat surface? Do you mean it'll be different depending on what I start with?

Comment: What you wrote down is the correct parametrisation of the curved surface. For the flat surface at the top, the parametrisation is $x = u \cos v$, $u = u \sin v$, $z = 2$, with $u \in [0,2]$ and $v \in [0, 2\pi]$. (So the only difference is that $z$ is equal to $2$ rather than $u$.)

Comment: Ah I see, but the first parametrization should have $u \in [0,2)$ technically right?(but this wouldn't matter since if we take integrals it's ignored)

Comment: I think it does go up to $u = 2$, since the "circular rim" is included in the region defined in your question. But like you say, this doesn't really matter...

Comment: One last question, $u$ in the second case is still ranging from 0 to 2 because it needs to "fill" the circle at the top right?

Comment: @PaulWoch Yeah, that's right.